# How to get the location of iPhone without "Find my iPhone"?

Tags: ios, iphone, macos-sierra

I have an iPad Air 2 and my daughter has an iPhone 5s with a shared iCloud account. Both have the latest iOS version (10.1.1 as of this post). Previously both can find each other. But my daughter is now during teenage, she doesn't want me to track her. She turned off "Find my iPhone". Are there anyways to override this control without touching her iPhone? Thank you in advance.
By the way, I also have a mac, perhaps it helps.

Comment: This is not the right forum for this...

Comment: However, I might recommend talking to your daughter. This isn't a coding/programming problem. This is a people problem, and people problems require people solutions.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: Alright, sorry. How to close it, I don't know?

Comment: You should ask this on the [**Ask Different Stack Exchange site**](http://apple.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 1):

I understand your concern as a father, but Apple made it all so clear that the privacy of the iphone belongs to the owner of the iphone. You can build a program in xcode with Core Location and MapKit to track the user location of the iphone at any given time. To do this, however, you have two types of privacy statements that you need to conform to when building an app to track the iphone.

1. Use location services when in use.
2. Use location services allways in use.

The first is for apps that are running in the foreground or in the background, but are running. I guess your daughter will not start this app. The second privacy statement is for apps that allways use location updates, even when they are not in use.

The problem is that the app will ask for permission to use location updates and your daughter can easily say no, which means that you have the same problem as with find my iphone.

Answer (score -1):

Like I said in comments, this is more of a relationship issue where your daughter doesn't want you to know where she is. If she's got internet access, she's likely in an arms race with you as far as privacy. No programming solution will give you the magic bullet to know where your daughter is at all times.

The answer to your problem is to sit down with your daughter and explain your concerns. Why do you want to know where your daughter is at all times? Why does her turning off her "Find my iPhone" concern you?

If she's paying for her phone, then she should have a say in how it is managed. If you're paying for it, you could make it a condition of her keeping the phone.